# What happens with ARC and an Objective C object inside a C++ object?

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I was surprised that this compiled without error. I didn't think it used to, when ARC first came out.

```
class SessionWriter
{
    NSString *sessionDir;
    ...
};
```

It looks like that `NSString` is released in the destructor by ARC. Where is this documented?

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C++ in general is rather poorly documented. The Objective-C 2.0 language itself lacks formal specification other than Apple's high-level tutorials and low-level API lists, and Objective-C++ has less still. Broadly speaking, it seems like you're kind of just supposed to trust that things "work" logically in the transition between C and C++ as the base language.

The Clang ARC docs do [touch on this a bit](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualified-fields-of-structs-and-unions), though they're actually describing the difference in behavior between Objective-C and Objective-C++ structs rather than C++ classes. It makes it pretty clear, though, that ARC does indeed work for Objective-C++ aggregates.

> nontrivally ownership-qualified types are considered non-POD: in C++11 terms, they are not trivially default constructible, copy constructible, move constructible, copy assignable, move assignable, or destructible. It is a violation of C++’s One Definition Rule to use a class outside of ARC that, under ARC, would have a nontrivially ownership-qualified member.
>
> #### Rationale
>
> Unlike in C, we can express all the necessary ARC semantics for ownership-qualified subobjects as suboperations of the (default) special member functions for the class. These functions then become non-trivial. This has the non-obvious result that the class will have a non-trivial copy constructor and non-trivial destructor; if this would not normally be true outside of ARC, objects of the type will be passed and returned in an ABI-incompatible manner.

Comment: That helps. The line about the One Definition Rule is confusing me. Can you explain more why using the class outside of ARC would be a problem? Is it because a non-ARC translation unit might try to inline a destructor and end up writing it differently, without the `release` in this case?

Comment: Not necessarily inlining a destructor so much as Clang having to generate two disparate definitions of the class cum and sine ARC.

Comment: Why would it ever need to do that? If some class `Foo` is compiled with ARC, then it's destructor will use ARC, and clients of `Foo` with ARC turned off will still call `Foo`'s destructor and get the right behavior.